# Change the backup folder to dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, location, dompdf

Using `dompdf` for generating documents in pdf how I can specify the location of the backup file in PHP?

```
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("file.pdf");
```

Comment: What is the "backup file"? dompdf creates pdf files, it doesn't create backups.

Comment: The files will be managed in the default download directory

Comment: You need to be more clear here as to what you are talking about. As it is now, it makes no sense, comment included. Those 3 lines of code don't make any backups. `load_html` loads the html file into memory and doesn't save it anywhere. For `render, I am unaware if it uses a temp file or memory (but I assume memory as there might not be a need to ). And stream would just output the file from memory after sending out a few headers.

Comment: The only place that I know of that uses a temporary directory is when downloading external images from the html file. If you want to change that, you can create a new instance of the `Options` class and call `setTempDir($pathToTemp)`. That instance you can pass in to the constructor when you create an instance of dompdf.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your pdf in a custom directory :

```
$file = 'mydirectory/myfile.pdf';
$content=$dompdf->output(array("compression" => 1));
file_put_contents($file,$content);
```

Comment: Just FYI, I think compression is on by default at least in all the versions I've used. Doesn't hurt to specify it, though.